# Solving differential equation step by step

Tags: differential-equations

Is it possible to see the details of DSolve? I mean that instead of getting the answer I would like to see the step-by-step solution, which result in correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, no. However, for some simple examples, [`WolframAlpha`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html) can show the steps. For example,

```
WolframAlpha["solve y'[x]+y[x]\[Equal]a Sin[x]", 
  {{"DifferentialEquationSolution", 2}, "Content"}, 
   PodStates -> {"DifferentialEquationSolution__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

[image]