# Is there an issue with calls to WolframAlpha from Mathematica?

Tags: functions, wolfram-alpha-queries

I was trying to use the step by step to get a solution to an integral, but it was failing, so I tried an even simpler example [*from the Wolfram documentation*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/UseWolframAlphaInsideANotebook.html)

```
  WolframAlpha["what is the distance to the moon?"]
```

The output is, with no other detail given

```
  $Failed
```

I have also tried an example posted as solution on this [*site*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191215/solving-differential-equation-step-by-step)

```
  WolframAlpha["solve y'[x]+y[x]\[Equal]a Sin[x]", 
  {{"DifferentialEquationSolution", 2}, "Content"}, 
   PodStates -> {"DifferentialEquationSolution__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

The result fails with a message

```
  Missing["NotAvailable"]
```

I am running MMA V14.0.0.0 on Windows 10, x86.

I am not sure if there is an issue with calling WA inside Mathematica, or my install got corrupted somehow. Any way to tell?

Note: As an aside, even direct calls to WA fail using $=$ or $==$ followed by an input, fail in the same way.

Comment: The [distance to the moon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkT33.png) computes, but the second one gives the same message as yours. (v12.2.0 on Win7-x64)

Comment: A more exact formulation `WolframAlpha["What is the distance from the Earth to the Moon?"]` works well in 14.0 on Windows & Linux.

Comment: @user64494: Thanks, that worked for this simple example, but any ideas why the second (a more realistic query) fails? Is it a bug?

Comment: Execute `WolframAlpha["Solve  y'[x]+y[x]\[Equal]a Sin[x]"]` and after that press the "Step-by-step solution" button.

Comment: @user64494: Thanks, that worked! I wonder if there was a large change made to the language processor that processes these inputs. This seems very restrictive as you may need to use exact syntax and it is not clear what that is supposed to be.

Comment: I understand you are interested in a step-by-step solution, not in the work of the certain command `WolframAlpha["solve y'[x]+y[x]\[Equal]a Sin[x]", 
  {{"DifferentialEquationSolution", 2}, "Content"}, 
   PodStates -> {"DifferentialEquationSolution__Step-by-step solution"}]`.

Comment: That failed with "Missing["NotAvailable"]"

Comment: This looks like a new bug, why the Close vote?

Comment: Bugs should be reported to the WRI. But since other users confirmed that WolframAlpha queries work, there must be something wrong on your computer/with your installation. Again, a thing to be communicated with the WRI, not SE.

Comment: @Domen: I would not characterize like that. Look at Syed's first comment. Also, in all cases, they figured out some special input to get it to work that has not been documented. This site is getting as bad as the Mathematics one.

Comment: **This site is getting as bad as the Mathematics one.** No way. That math stackexchange site is absolutely terrible. No other site could possibility be as bad as that one :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because queries  about Wolfram Alpha are considered off-topic on this forum. For the site visitor, the software called Mathematica requires precise entry of expressions; any deviations count as a syntax error; whereas Wolfram Alpha uses an A.I. engine to parse and interpret language.

Answer (score 3):

(i)
A more exact formulation `WolframAlpha["What is the distance from the Earth to the Moon?"]` works well in 14.0 on Windows & Linux.

(ii) `WolframAlpha["Solve  y'[x]+y[x]\[Equal]a Sin[x]",  PodStates -> "Step-by-step solution"]` works well in 14.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

```
WolframAlpha["solve y'[x]+y[x]\[Equal]a Sin[x]", {{"Result", 2}, 
  "Content"}, PodStates -> {"Result__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I don't really know how to get the right `PodStates` names in all cases, though. I started with `WolframAlpha["solve y'[x]+y[x]\[Equal]0"]`, got the step-by-step solution, and got the "Subpod content" from the + drop-down menu of the pod.

Comment: The same output is produced by `WolframAlpha["solve y'[x]+y[x]\[Equal]a Sin[x]", 
 PodStates -> {"Result__Step-by-step solution"}]` as stated in my answer. Did you read my answer before having posted yours?

Comment: @user64494 Not really. I was trying to figure out how to use Mathematica to find the answer. I thought it was helpful to explain how to do it. It seems most on this site, except the better older answers, don't explain how to figure out things. It wasn't clear why you thought it "works well"; or how you got your answer, which is different (and simpler!) than what I found; and I have no way of knowing how things work on Windows and how it is different.

Comment: Goofy(@ does not work.): )Sorry, you don't describe what `{{"Result", 2}, 
  "Content"}` does. It seems the one does nothing.